# Async worker died! ... clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to class java.lang.String

Tags: stormcrawler

I'm new to the crawler world and Java so please set me straight.

I've been successful injecting my target URLs but when I run the crawler local my async worker dies...when running remote the crawler does not die, but it does not crawl my URLs in seeds.txt either.

Googling has not helped me in this case.

Even in --remote run I'm getting no crawls (see image):

[crawler stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXJbr.png)

Below is the print out of the situation.

Any idea what's causing this?

```
...
[snipped]
...

7841 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2000):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100040091f2000f type:create cxid:0xdc zxid:0x3c txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/storm/errors/crawler-1-1574269039/spout Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /storm/errors/crawler-1-1574269039/spout
7842 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2000):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100040091f2000f type:create cxid:0xdf zxid:0x3d txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/storm/errors/crawler-1-1574269039/spout Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /storm/errors/crawler-1-1574269039/spout
7842 [Thread-49-spout-executor[14 14]] ERROR o.a.s.d.executor - 
java.lang.ClassCastException: class clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (clojure.lang.PersistentVector is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.util.ConfUtils.getString(ConfUtils.java:74) ~[dev1-0.1.jar:?]
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.AbstractSpout.open(AbstractSpout.java:188) ~[dev1-0.1.jar:?]
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.AggregationSpout.open(AggregationSpout.java:98) ~[dev1-0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__10112$fn__10127.invoke(executor.clj:609) ~[storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__624.invoke(util.clj:482) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
7843 [Thread-55-spout-executor[17 17]] ERROR o.a.s.d.executor - 
java.lang.ClassCastException: class clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (clojure.lang.PersistentVector is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.util.ConfUtils.getString(ConfUtils.java:74) ~[dev1-0.1.jar:?]
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.AbstractSpout.open(AbstractSpout.java:188) ~[dev1-0.1.jar:?]
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.AggregationSpout.open(AggregationSpout.java:98) ~[dev1-0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__10112$fn__10127.invoke(executor.clj:609) ~[storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__624.invoke(util.clj:482) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
7845 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2000):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100040091f2000f type:create cxid:0xe6 zxid:0x3e txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/storm/errors/crawler-1-1574269039/spout Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /storm/errors/crawler-1-1574269039/spout
7839 [Thread-33-spout-executor[9 9]] INFO  c.d.s.e.p.AbstractSpout - [spout #1]  assigned shard ID 1
7846 [Thread-33-spout-executor[9 9]] ERROR o.a.s.util - Async loop died!
java.lang.ClassCastException: class clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (clojure.lang.PersistentVector is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.util.ConfUtils.getString(ConfUtils.java:74) ~[dev1-0.1.jar:?]
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.AbstractSpout.open(AbstractSpout.java:188) ~[dev1-0.1.jar:?]
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.AggregationSpout.open(AggregationSpout.java:98) ~[dev1-0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__10112$fn__10127.invoke(executor.clj:609) ~[storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__624.invoke(util.clj:482) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
7846 [Thread-33-spout-executor[9 9]] ERROR o.a.s.d.executor - 
java.lang.ClassCastException: class clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (clojure.lang.PersistentVector is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.util.ConfUtils.getString(ConfUtils.java:74) ~[dev1-0.1.jar:?]
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.AbstractSpout.open(AbstractSpout.java:188) ~[dev1-0.1.jar:?]
        at com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.AggregationSpout.open(AggregationSpout.java:98) ~[dev1-0.1.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$fn__10112$fn__10127.invoke(executor.clj:609) ~[storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__624.invoke(util.clj:482) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
7847 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2000):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100040091f2000f type:create cxid:0xf0 zxid:0x42 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/storm/errors/crawler-1-1574269039/spout Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /storm/errors/crawler-1-1574269039/spout
7863 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2000):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100040091f2000f type:create cxid:0x105 zxid:0x4b txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/storm/errors/crawler-1-1574269039/spout-last-error Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /storm/errors/crawler-1-1574269039/spout-last-error
7863 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2000):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100040091f2000f type:create cxid:0x106 zxid:0x4c txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/storm/errors/crawler-1-1574269039/spout-last-error Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /storm/errors/crawler-1-1574269039/spout-last-error
7875 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2000):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100040091f2000f type:create cxid:0x111 zxid:0x50 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/storm/errors/crawler-1-1574269039/spout-last-error Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /storm/errors/crawler-1-1574269039/spout-last-error
7875 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2000):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100040091f2000f type:create cxid:0x112 zxid:0x51 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/storm/errors/crawler-1-1574269039/spout-last-error Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /storm/errors/crawler-1-1574269039/spout-last-error
7875 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:2000):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x100040091f2000f type:create cxid:0x114 zxid:0x53 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/storm/errors/crawler-1-1574269039/spout-last-error Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /storm/errors/crawler-1-1574269039/spout-last-error
7886 [Thread-19-spout-executor[12 12]] ERROR o.a.s.util - Halting process: ("Worker died")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Worker died")
        at org.apache.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:341) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__10799$fn__10800.invoke(worker.clj:788) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__9997$fn__9998.invoke(executor.clj:281) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__624.invoke(util.clj:494) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
7886 [Thread-17-spout-executor[8 8]] ERROR o.a.s.util - Halting process: ("Worker died")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Worker died")
        at org.apache.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:341) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__10799$fn__10800.invoke(worker.clj:788) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__9997$fn__9998.invoke(executor.clj:281) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__624.invoke(util.clj:494) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
7886 [Thread-49-spout-executor[14 14]] ERROR o.a.s.util - Halting process: ("Worker died")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Worker died")
        at org.apache.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:341) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__10799$fn__10800.invoke(worker.clj:788) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__9997$fn__9998.invoke(executor.clj:281) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__624.invoke(util.clj:494) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
7892 [Thread-39-spout-executor[16 16]] ERROR o.a.s.util - Halting process: ("Worker died")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Worker died")
        at org.apache.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:341) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__10799$fn__10800.invoke(worker.clj:788) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__9997$fn__9998.invoke(executor.clj:281) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__624.invoke(util.clj:494) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
7892 [Thread-35-spout-executor[11 11]] ERROR o.a.s.util - Halting process: ("Worker died")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Worker died")
        at org.apache.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:341) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__10799$fn__10800.invoke(worker.clj:788) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__9997$fn__9998.invoke(executor.clj:281) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__624.invoke(util.clj:494) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
7893 [Thread-47-spout-executor[10 10]] ERROR o.a.s.util - Halting process: ("Worker died")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Worker died")
        at org.apache.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:341) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__10799$fn__10800.invoke(worker.clj:788) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__9997$fn__9998.invoke(executor.clj:281) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__624.invoke(util.clj:494) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
7895 [Thread-55-spout-executor[17 17]] ERROR o.a.s.util - Halting process: ("Worker died")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Worker died")
        at org.apache.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:341) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__10799$fn__10800.invoke(worker.clj:788) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__9997$fn__9998.invoke(executor.clj:281) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__624.invoke(util.clj:494) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
7895 [Thread-41-spout-executor[13 13]] ERROR o.a.s.util - Halting process: ("Worker died")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Worker died")
        at org.apache.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:341) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__10799$fn__10800.invoke(worker.clj:788) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__9997$fn__9998.invoke(executor.clj:281) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__624.invoke(util.clj:494) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
7895 [Thread-53-spout-executor[15 15]] ERROR o.a.s.util - Halting process: ("Worker died")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Worker died")
        at org.apache.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:341) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__10799$fn__10800.invoke(worker.clj:788) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__9997$fn__9998.invoke(executor.clj:281) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at org.apache.storm.util$async_loop$fn__624.invoke(util.clj:494) [storm-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.util.ConfUtils.getString(ConfUtils.java:74) ~[dev1-0.1.jar:?]

```
 72     public static String getString(Map<String, Object> conf, String key,
 73             String defaultValue) {
 74         return (String) Utils.get(conf, key, defaultValue);
 75     }
 76
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to a mismatch between the version of StormCrawler and the version of your configuration for ES, in particular, _ es.status.bucket.sort.field_ wasn't multivalued until recently.

Either use the version of the conf that is compatible with your version of SC, [here for 1.15](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/1.15/external/elasticsearch/es-conf.yaml), or alternatively, checkout SC from the master branch and compile it.

Comment: I've tested with both the master and 2x branch with the same behavior (both have the multivalued sort.field). My ES is 7.4.2. Do I need to downgrade ES?

Comment: I've included an image in the original post of a --remote run that doesnt seem to error our, but now crawls are performed. I'm wondering if I missed a simple step..seeds.txt has one entry: http://reddit[.]com obviously without the brackets but just as a test

Comment: The master branch is based on 7.3.0 -> https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/pom.xml

Comment: Check the content of the status index, if no URLs have been injected, the crawler will have nothing to do

Comment: Julien...cloned the master branch, and copied over the ES resources from master too. Replacing es-conf.yaml with the 1.15 tag fixes my error above despite running SC 1.15 from master. I'm marking this as the answer but am confused why this file in particular needed to be reverted to a previous release. Is it because 2.X is the priority now?

Comment: the master branch contains 1.16-SNAPSHOT, not 1.15. the es conf in 1.16 is not compatible with 1.15 

This is unrelated to 2.x, which I am hoping to release at alongside 1.16, we'll see.

Comment: What I'm saying is the es-conf in 1.16 is not compatible with 1.16. That's what gave me this error^ -- the fix was to revert the es conf to 1.15 and with everything else left as 1.16..